Issue with cors policy in my webflow website
I have an issue with my webflow website and its API integration called Xano.
A couple of days ago, the interface that creates the API request to the routes created in Xano disappeared. When I log into the webflow I see this sort of error

abm-website-staging.design.webflow.com/:1 Access to fetch at
'https://webflow.com/api/user/readOnlyData' from origin
'https://abm-website-staging.design.webflow.com' has been blocked by
CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
'https://preview.webflow.com' that is not equal to the supplied
origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an
opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The cool thing is that my domain is connected to Cloudflare, so according to info on the internet, I can use this proxy to set up the rule to bypass this error. If anyone can give me a little guidance here, I would be much appreciated
